# Matlab equivalent of Python's "pass" statement

Tags: python, matlab

In python you can issue something like

```
if <condition>:
    pass
```

This can come in handy as a placeholder for future code placement. What's the equivalent of "pass" in matlab when it comes to these kind of uses?

Comment: That's a null operation. I think leaving it empty or just adding a comment line is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/117519-do-nothing-command-in-matlab

You can just use a semicolon. You could also immediately go to `end` as Christian suggested.

The `pass` command is necessary in Python, because 1) indentation determines the scope for `if/for/while` or for functions, and 2) there is no way of indicating that a block has ended except to un-indent. The combination of these two makes a no-op command pretty much necessary for the parser to work correctly. In Matlab, you have `end`, so you don't have the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

There is not equivalent for that, but since you have to declare the *"end"* of a function or a condition in MATLAB, you can leave it empty.

For example:

```
if (condition)
end
```

or just leave a comment:

```
if (condition)
    % future code here
end
```